# Making a Thread Safe socket class in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, multithreading, sockets

I have some question about `Sockets` and some concepts of `Thread Safe` sockets. I have 2 classes, a **server class** and a **client class** :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

// Loosely inspired on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx

namespace AsynchronousSockets
{
    class Server
    {
        class StateObject
        {
            public Socket connection = null;

            // Note that I use a very small buffer size
            // for this example. Normally you'd like a much
            // larger buffer. But this small buffer size nicely
            // demonstrates getting the entire message in multiple
            // pieces.
            public const int bufferSize = 100000; 
            public byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
            public int expectedMessageLength = 0;
            public int receivedMessageLength = 0;
            public byte[] message = null;
        }

        static ManualResetEvent acceptDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        const int listenPort = 2500;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("This is the server");

            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
            Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(100);

                while (true)
                {
                    acceptDone.Reset();

                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Listening on port {0}", listenPort);
                    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback), listener);

                    acceptDone.WaitOne();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }        

        static void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                acceptDone.Set();

                Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

                StateObject state = new StateObject();
                state.connection = handler;

                handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize,
                    SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        static void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
                Socket handler = state.connection;

                int read = handler.EndReceive(ar);

                if (read > 0)
                {
                    Console.Out.WriteLine("Read {0} bytes", read);

                    if (state.expectedMessageLength == 0)
                    {
                        // Extract how much data to expect from the first 4 bytes
                        // then configure buffer sizes and copy the already received
                        // part of the message.
                        state.expectedMessageLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(state.buffer, 0);
                        state.message = new byte[state.expectedMessageLength];
                        Array.ConstrainedCopy(state.buffer, 4, state.message, 0, Math.Min(StateObject.bufferSize - 4, state.expectedMessageLength - state.receivedMessageLength));
                        state.receivedMessageLength += read - 4;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Array.ConstrainedCopy(state.buffer, 0, state.message, state.receivedMessageLength, Math.Min(StateObject.bufferSize, state.expectedMessageLength - state.receivedMessageLength));
                        state.receivedMessageLength += read;
                    }                                       

                    // Check if we received the entire message. If not
                    // continue listening, else close the connection
                    // and reconstruct the message.
                    if (state.receivedMessageLength < state.expectedMessageLength)
                    {
                        handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.bufferSize,
                            SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                        handler.Close();

                        Console.Out.WriteLine("Received message: \n");
                        Console.Out.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.message));
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using Client;
using System.Management;

// Loosely inspired on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx

namespace AsynchronousSockets
{
    class Program
    {
        static readonly IPAddress serverIP = IPAddress.Loopback;
        const int serverPort = 2500;

        static ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        static ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Out.WriteLine("This is the client");
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Write the message to send. End with an emtpy line to start the transmisison. \n");

            string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;

            for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
            {
                String message = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " : Message sended by " + userName + ".";

                Console.Out.WriteLine("Sending message: ...\n");
                Console.Out.Write(message);
                Console.Out.Write("\n");

                Thread.Sleep(10);
                Console.Out.WriteLine("Sleeping ...\n");

                SendMessageAsync(message);
            }

            Console.Out.WriteLine("Sending finished by " + userName + "! \n");
        }

        static void SendMessageAsync(string message)
        {                        
            // Initiate connecting to the server
            Socket connection = Connect();

            // block this thread until we have connected
            // normally your program would just continue doing other work
            // but we've got nothing to do :)
            connectDone.WaitOne();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Connected to server");

            // Start sending the data
            SendData(connection, message);
            sendDone.WaitOne();
            Console.Out.WriteLine("Message successfully sent");
        }        

        static Socket Connect()
        {
            try
            {             
                IPEndPoint serverAddress = new IPEndPoint(serverIP, serverPort);
                Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                client.BeginConnect(serverAddress, new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback), client);

                return client;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                return null;               
            }
        }

        static void SendData(Socket connection, string message)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                // We store how much data the server should expect
                // in the first 4 bytes of the data we're going to send
                byte[] head = BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length);

                byte[] total = new byte[data.Length + head.Length];
                head.CopyTo(total, 0);
                data.CopyTo(total, head.Length);

                connection.BeginSend(total, 0, total.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallBack), connection);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                client.EndConnect(ar);
                connectDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void SendCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
                int bytes = client.EndSend(ar);

                Console.Out.WriteLine("A total of {0} bytes were sent to the server", bytes);

                sendDone.Set();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see that as soon as the `client.exe` starts, if `server.exe` is running it will recieve some messages sended by `Client` class.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++)
{
    String message = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss") + " : Message sended by " + userName + ".";

    Console.Out.WriteLine("Sending message: ...\n");
    Console.Out.Write(message);
    Console.Out.Write("\n");

    Thread.Sleep(10);
    Console.Out.WriteLine("Sleeping ...\n");

    SendMessageAsync(message);
}
```

and this loop will be executed 10000 times with the pause between loops of 10 milliseconds. I start 3 clients from 3 places (different windows users logged on the same time), and the the server log is :

```
......
02-06-2014 11:24:30 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\user1.
Listening on port 2500
Listening on port 2500
Listening on port 2500
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 7 bytes
Received message: 

02-06-2014 11:24:30 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\user2.
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 7 bytes
Received message: 

02-06-2014 11:24:30 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\user3.
Listening on port 2500
Listening on port 2500
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 7 bytes
Received message: 

02-06-2014 11:24:30 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\user2.
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 7 bytes
Received message: 

02-06-2014 11:24:30 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\user3.
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 7 bytes
Received message: 

02-06-2014 11:24:30 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\user1.
Listening on port 2500
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 8 bytes
Read 7 bytes
Received message:
......
```

after all 3 clients stop, i open the log file in 'Notepad++' and i count the following results :

count "MyComputer-PC\user1" => 8903

count "MyComputer-PC\user2" => 8464

count "MyComputer-PC\user3" => 8990

Why this? Some data had been lost, it should render 10.000 10.000 10.000 ...

How can i solve this?

Another thing that i want to ask si how to make a socket thread safe.

**EDIT**

i am actually getting this log when the socket is refused

```
connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
Sending message: ...

03-06-2014 09:35:58 : Message sended by MyComputer-PC\User1.
Sleeping ...

connection.Connected False
connection.Blocking True
Connected to server
A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied
Message successfully sent
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you put my post on hold? I think i have not violated the therms of stackoverflow

Comment: It's on hold for the reason listed.  It's too broad.

Comment: it is to what? please explain, i might do the same mistake over and over again. thank you.

Comment: The close reason is listed right there.  You only need to read it.

Comment: `There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.` so i writed to much? this is impossible ... all i wanted to do is just to provide enough detalis, not just say that is not working, like other said ...

Comment: You have a very large block of code, you say it doesn't work, and then ask for it to be fixed.  The scope of the problem is simply too large for an SO question.  If you can narrow down the problem to a small code snippet, and describe the problem narrowly rather than just saying that it doesn't work, then perhaps the question could become appropriately scoped.

Comment: Listen, i put the whole code because it is better for the people to see all, and the problem is narrow down at `for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++) ...` , it is better to put all the code, to see what is going wrong ... next time if i put the code on pastebin it will be ok?

Comment: You should restrict the code posted to a minimal reproducible example, rather than posting hundreds of lines of irrelevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem looks to be the use of `ManualResetEvent`s in the client. Remember, a `ManualResetEvent` must be *manually* reset, otherwise all `WaitOne()` calls after the event has been `Set()` will return immediately. As a result, your client will not be waiting for the socket to be connected before trying to send data after the first message is sent, as indicated by the following message which I saw logged when I ran it on my machine:

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied

Try changing your `ManualResetEvent`s to `AutoResetEvent`s (which automatically reset after `WaitOne()` returns true) in the client, which should resolve the issue.

Comment: 1-> `ManualResetEvent must be manually reset` -> how i can reset it manually? it is a command?      2-> so basically what you say is that normally, if you have few sockets, it will not go to `WaitOne()` line, but if you have many, if the server is overwhelmed, the data is loosed? Wouldn't be a clever move to put there something like, 'wait till i process this socket, otherwise reject other sockets' and client be like `if i was rejected, i will try over 100 miliseconds again`??  3-> where do i see this message? `A request to send ...` ?? Thank you very much for your response!

Comment: @Damian 1) use `Reset()`. 2) The problem (at least when I ran it) was not data getting lost, but data never getting sent because the client was trying to send data before the socket was ready (as  `connectDone.WaitOne()` wasn't ever waiting). 3) These messages were written to the console window.

Comment: 1-> where do i put this `Reset()` method?   2-> so the problem must be at the client, right?      3-> when i test this, i test on a windows 7 without a `visual studio 2012`, can i see this log somewhere else? thanks.

Comment: EDIT : see my log http://pastebin.com/cKwbeh5W , this is what i get when sockets are refused

Comment: @Damian As I indicate in my answer, you don't need to add `Reset()`, just change your `ManualResetEvent`s to `AutoResetEvent`s in the client.

Comment: it gives me the following error `Error 1 The type or namespace name 'AutoResetEvents' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\MiloTCP2\Client\Client\Client.cs 50 16 Client
`  why is that??

Comment: @Damian it's `AutoResetEvent`.

Comment: now it is stopping at the first `No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:2500` message see this log http://pastebin.com/tPayjRbd

Comment: i think i solve it with a `connectDone.Reset();` that stands aftrer the `Console.Out.WriteLine("Message successfully sent");` line

Comment: now i am having problems with REQUEST / RESPONSE type of socket, i want to send a request socket and get back a response, kinda like in a WEBSERVICE, can you point me in the right direction? thank you.